# disable launchpad capabilities in OS X cocoa

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa, nsviewcontroller

Is there a way to disable the launchpad (3 finger slide) ability while an cocoa application is running? I am trying to make it harder for them to go elsewhere or do something different while the current application is running. I know that they still have other ways, but I just want to discourage it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To prevent the user from switching applications *in general* (not just using Launchpad), use the `NSApplicationPresentationDisableProcessSwitching` flag for the `+ [NSApp setPresentationOptions:]` method.

More information is available in Apple's [Kiosk Mode Technical Note](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/technotes/KioskMode/Introduction/Introduction.html).

Comment: Thanks so much Dusk! Where exactly would I put this? In the AppDelegate controller? When I tried it doesn't give the option of using 'NSApplicationPresentationDisableProcessSwitching'. I am really new to Swift and Xcode, so I appreciate any details.

Comment: From Apple's Page that you suggested this code   `-(void) awakeFromNib {
    @try {
    NSApplicationPresentationOptions options = NSApplicationPreentationHideDock + NSApplicationPresentationHIdeMenuBar;
    
    [NSApp setPresentationOptions:options];
    
    }
    @catch(NSException * exception) {
    NSLog(@"Error.  Make sure you have a valid combination of options.");
    }` Didn't work for me unfortunately. What am I missing?

Comment: That code is Objective-C, not Swift. It also contains at least one typo (`Preentation`).

Comment: Yeah, sorry. I have since fixed the typo, but it doesn't work. Do you know what it would look like in Swift? is "-(void)" now replaced with "override fun awakeFromNib" ?

Comment: `override func viewDidAppear() {
        let presOptions: NSApplicationPresentationOptions = ([.FullScreen,.AutoHideMenuBar])

        let optionsDictionary = [NSFullScreenModeApplicationPresentationOptions :
            NSNumber(unsignedLong: presOptions.rawValue)]
        
        self.view.enterFullScreenMode(NSScreen.mainScreen()!, withOptions:optionsDictionary)
        self.view.wantsLayer = true
    }`  I found this, but I need it to work without going into full-screen mode and I can't seem to get the syntax right.